# How to default sliderInput to 'play' when the app window opens/refreshes

Tags: r, animation, shiny

The example is reproducible so when you run the code below, you would be able to see that the `play button` becomes responsive only once the `update slider` is clicked.

I would like to add a condition on the `play button` so that if the user presses `play` it takes the current controls as it is and runs the animation. But if the user changes the controls (speed and interval), the main slider updates only when the `action button` is clicked.

I have achieved this but when the app loads, the user is having to click on the 'update' button first to initialise the reactivity of the `play button` and this is not very obvious when one loads the app.

I would be okay if the app defaults to `play` when it loads OR a way to pass a condition on the `play button` will also be just fine.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("tester"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(id="sidebar",
                 uiOutput("slider"),
                 actionButton("change_controls",tags$b("Update controls")),
                 uiOutput("speed_value"), 
                 uiOutput("step_size")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4(textOutput("selectedtime"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  ##make the updates reactive to the action button
  observeEvent(input$change_controls,{
    val <- input$timeRange
    updateSliderInput(session, "timeRange",value=val)

  })

  ##datetime slider definition.
  output$slider <- renderUI({

    ##make this slider reactive when the actionbutton is updated.
    input$change_controls

    ##isolating their dependencies so the slider does not refresh whiles changes are being made.
    steps <- isolate(input$step_size)
    speed <- isolate(input$speed)


    ##slider definition
    sliderInput("timeRange", label = "time:", width = '600px',
                min = 1,
                max = 10000,
                value = 1,
                step = 60*steps,
                animate = animationOptions(interval = 3200 - (speed*300))
    )

  })

  ##animation speed control
  output$speed_value <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("speed",
                label = div(style='width:300px;',
                            div(style='float:left;', 'slower'),
                            div(style='float:right;', 'faster')),
                min = 1, 
                max = 10, 
                value = 6, 
                width = '300px')

  })

  ##time step definition by user
  output$step_size <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("step_size","Steps:",
                min = 10, max = 60, value = 1, width = '300px')
  })

  ##OUTPUT
  observe({
    output$selectedtime <- renderText({
      paste(format(input$timeRange))
    })

  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if if i know what you want. First of all, the variable "minimum.slider" in your sliderInput "timeRange" does not exist. However, is there a reason you put the sliderInput("speed", and "stepsize" in a renderUI() ? It should work fine if you put it in the ui-part of your code.

Comment: I have removed the minimum.slider variable. apologies. The speed and step_size do other things in the bigger app that I am working with. But yes I agree they can go in the ui part of the code. What I want is to enable a condition that 'if user presses play the slider animates without having to click on 'update slider' action button. But if the step size and speed are changed, the updates feed into the 'timeRange' slider only when the 'update slider' button is clicked.